# dx texture don't change on time?

Tags: directx, textures, direct3d

I'm rendering 2D sprites with DX9 using a vertex buffer (DrawPrimitive).
some animations got different texture files with different sizes.

Now I get the following problem: on the very single frame where I'm switching between two animations that have different texture files (for example when start walking or when finish walking and begin standing), it's rendering with the coordinates for the *new* texture, but still presenting the old texture. This looks as if I did'nt set the texture for the new animation. only problem is - I did.

How I understood what's the problem: I took a screenshot right on that frame, and noticed that it renders one texture with coordinates fitting to the other texture.

In my rendering function I first get the new texture and send it to DX, than calculating the coords, and in the end I render my vertices with the coords and the new texture set. I checked and debugged it million times and all the values are correct, and yet the bug happens.

any ideas why this might happen?

thanks!

Edit: added some code:

```
    // Render a quad using the vertex buffer
void CGraphicsManager::RenderQuadViaVertexBuffer(const SVertex* pVertices) const
{

    // Increase renders count
    this->m_RenderCount++;

    // vb_vertices now points to our vertices inside the Vertex buffer, so
    // to fill in our VB, we copy to vb_vertices.
    memcpy(this->m_pVertexBufferBuffPtr + this->m_OffsetInVertexBuffer, pVertices, sizeof(SVertex) * (VERTICES_IN_QUAD));

    // Render the rectanlge using the vertices we got. 
    this->m_pD3dDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, this->m_OffsetInVertexBuffer, PRIMITIVES_IN_QUAD);

    // Increment the offset in the vertex buffer
    this->m_OffsetInVertexBuffer += VERTICES_IN_QUAD;

}
// Render a quad
void CGraphicsManager::Render(const STexture& p_Texture, SLocation p_RenderLocation, SSize p_RenderSize, const SQuad& p_TextureQuad, SfColor p_RenderColor, ERenderEffects p_RenderEffect) const
{
    // Set render effect
    this->SetRenderEffect(p_RenderEffect);

    // Set texture
    this->SetTexture(p_Texture);

    // Set the vertex needed for the rendering
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].Position.x = p_RenderLocation.x;
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].Position.y = p_RenderLocation.y;
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].Position.z = 0.0f;
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].color      = p_RenderColor;
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].tv         = p_TextureQuad.left;
    VerticesForQuadRender[0].tu         = p_TextureQuad.top;

    VerticesForQuadRender[1].Position.x = p_RenderLocation.x + p_RenderSize.x;
    VerticesForQuadRender[1].Position.y = p_RenderLocation.y;
    VerticesForQuadRender[1].Position.z = 0.0f;
    VerticesForQuadRender[1].color      = p_RenderColor;
    VerticesForQuadRender[1].tv         = p_TextureQuad.right;
    VerticesForQuadRender[1].tu         = p_TextureQuad.top;

    VerticesForQuadRender[2].Position.x = p_RenderLocation.x;
    VerticesForQuadRender[2].Position.y = p_RenderLocation.y + p_RenderSize.y;
    VerticesForQuadRender[2].Position.z = 0.0f;
    VerticesForQuadRender[2].color      = p_RenderColor;
    VerticesForQuadRender[2].tv         = p_TextureQuad.left;
    VerticesForQuadRender[2].tu         = p_TextureQuad.bottom;

    VerticesForQuadRender[3].Position.x = p_RenderLocation.x + p_RenderSize.x;
    VerticesForQuadRender[3].Position.y = p_RenderLocation.y + p_RenderSize.y;
    VerticesForQuadRender[3].Position.z = 0.0f;
    VerticesForQuadRender[3].color      = p_RenderColor;
    VerticesForQuadRender[3].tv         = p_TextureQuad.right;
    VerticesForQuadRender[3].tu         = p_TextureQuad.bottom;

    this->RenderQuadViaVertexBuffer(VerticesForQuadRender);
}


// Starts a rendering frame
bool CGraphicsManager::StartFrame()
{
    // Clear texture
    this->ClearTexture();

    // Zero renders count
    this->m_RenderCount = 0;

    // Clear screen
    if (!this->ClearScreen())
    {
        this->ResetDevice();
        return false;
    }

    // Begin new rendering scene
    if (FAILED(this->m_pD3dDevice->BeginScene()))
    {
        this->ResetDevice();
        return false;
    }

    // Set render from our vertex buffer
    this->BeginRenderFromVertexBuffer();

    return true;
}


// Finish rendering
bool CGraphicsManager::EndFrame()
{
    // Unlock vertex buffer
    this->m_pVertexBuffer->Unlock();

    // Notify the device that we're finished rendering for this frame
    if (FAILED(this->m_pD3dDevice->EndScene()))
    {
        this->ResetDevice();
        return false;
    }

    // Present scene
    if(FAILED(this->m_pD3dDevice->Present(NULL,     //Source rectangle to display, NULL for all of it
                        NULL,                       //Destination rectangle, NULL to fill whole display
                        NULL,                       //Target window, if NULL uses device window set in CreateDevice
                        NULL )))                    //Dirty Region, set it to NULL
    {
        this->ResetDevice();
        return false;
    }

    // Finish rendering
    return true;
}

// This function must be called before rendering textured surfaces
void CGraphicsManager::BeginRenderFromVertexBuffer() const
{
        // Lock the vertex buffer (unlock on release) and get the pointer to the begining of the buffer
        HRESULT hr = this->m_pVertexBuffer->Lock
           (0,                                      // Offset, we want to start at the beginning
            0,                                      //SizeToLock, 0 means lock the whole thing
            (void**)&this->m_pVertexBufferBuffPtr,  //If successful, this will point to the data in the vertex buffer
            0); 

        ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr), "Failed to lock vertex buffer! (err: " << hr << ")");

    // Set offset in vertex buffer back to 0
    this->m_OffsetInVertexBuffer = 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the code for SetRenderEffect and SetTexture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can see your problem you are copying data into an locked vertex buffer and then rendering that data.  You can't do this.  The data in the locked vertex buffer is not actually valid yet.  It only becomes valid once you unlock it.  This is because the data you are filling in is in main memory and may actually be shadowing memory on the graphics card.  When you unlock it copies the data across to the graphics card.

As such if you lock/unlock for each draw call everything works fine because you are forcing the copy back.

As you have found, though, this is far from optimal.

What you should be doing is calculating all your quad vertex positions in one pass.  Then you need to go through and render all the quads (Ideally without swapping texture/shader/etc every call).

One way to do this would be to fill your vertex buffer as you are doing and then store the draw commands in a vertex buffer.  This would require you storing things like texture, effect used etc.  You can then run through the list and render everything from the vertex buffer you have already filled.

If you then sort things by texture and shader constants (to minimise state changes) you will find your performance is many many times better.  Although you will need to mark your vertex buffer as "dynamic" and its advisable to use the D3DLOCK_DISCARD flag when you lock the vertex buffer as this will discard the data currently in the vertex buffer (Basically it will return you a totally new block of memory to fill and won't copy anything from the card) instead of blocking and waiting for the GPU to finish using it.

I hope thats some help!

Answer (score 1):

When you say "coordinates for the new texture", are you reffering to this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping ?

If the sprite gets the old texture when you are updating it, it could be a few things.

1 : How dose your renderpipeline work? do you set each texture for each drawcall?
- what im looking for is if you just set the texture once and not perdrawcall (or if you sort this with batches)

2 : are you sure that you bind your new texture?

could you post some code on your draw function?

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply.

1. yep I'm referring to UV mapping

2. I got a mechanism to set textures only when necessary, but I suspected that this might be the source of the problem so I already disabled it. right now, I set the texture before every render call. - still happens.
3. yes, as I mentioned above as an attempt to solve this bug I changed the code to the point where before every render I set the texture and coordinates, regardless if necessary. I also debugged the very problematic frame and everything seems ok.

Comment: if you force a new texture every frame and for every drawcall, and it still dont work it could be something with the texture it self (you could have acidently put in the same texture) if you cold post some code that would help!

Comment: The texture itself is ok, otherwise it wouldn't work in the next frame either. the problem is just in the single frame that replace the texture. I just debugged it and I saw that I was setting the right texture and coords (checked the texture pointer and UV), but as soon as I go over the line that present the frame itself (pD3dDev->Present) it was rendered with the wrong texture! It act as if I never called the 'SetTexture' func, but I just saw that I did and I double checked the texture I was setting. it's so weird! that's why I suspect my logic is fine but im doing something wrong with DX

Comment: DX is probably working just fine, and it´s a bigger chance you have missed something or there is some thing not going as you expect it should. ( it´s more or less allways is that way )

you could debug it with pix, to see if there is any kind of wierd behavour or something.
another thing i was thinking of was a gpu stall, but that wouldent affect the texture.

Could you post your rendering code?

Comment: Off-course DX is working fine :)  but that doesn't mean that I use it properly. All I'm saying, I'm very positive that the problem is not in my vertices calculations or texture fetch.
anyway, I posted some of the code. also, I found out something interesting - If I put a "BeginRenderFromVertexBuffer()" call before every render (which as you can see creates a vertex buffer lock), it works without the glitch (but also drop FPS to half, obviously..)  This makes me even more sure that the UV and texture are correct. Im checking PIX now ill let you know if found anything.